# Property 'API_BASE_URL' does not exist on type '{}'. Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I get this error when I call my API_URL that I defined in my enviroment.ts file in a service class.

Error: src/app/product/product.service.ts:12:25 - error TS2339: Property 'API_BASE_URL' does not exist on type '{}'.

12   baseUrl = environment.API_BASE_URL;

**enviroment.ts
**

```
export const environment = {
    production :false,
    API_BASE_URL : 'http://localhost:8092'
}
```

**enviroment.development.ts
**

```
export const environment = {};
```

**product.service.ts
**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from '../product';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  baseUrl = environment.API_BASE_URL;


  createProduct(product: Product){ 
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, product);
  }
  getProductList(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }

}
```

I think I showed the URL correctly. It was actually running before I made changes to the service class. But now it throws errors. How can i solve it. Should I take the URL elsewhere or specify a type?

Comment: The answer seems to hide in your question. Is it possible that you're using the development mode? You should put a value for the `API_BASE_URL` in the `environment.development.ts` file as well.

Answer (score 1):

first you can try define API_BASE_URL in your enviroment.development.ts file as an empty string.  Like this:

```
API_BASE_URL : ''
```

The other thing i notice, i dont know if is only an error in the post is that you put "enviroment.ts" ... and it should be "enviroNment.ts, with an "N" letter between o and m letters.

Comment: I misspelled the file names while writing :) By the way, your advice worked. Thank you

Comment: im glad your problem got resolved, one more thing:  wy do you use "environment.development.ts"? 

i mean, angular read environment.ts as a dev for default.   And environment.prod.ts for production when you use --prod mode.

Comment: I have no idea. I was an amateur with Angular. That's why I may not have paid much attention to the distinction. :)